# Ubuntu20.04 + WLS1, APT broken after downgrading libc

Tags: ubuntu, apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Ubuntu20.04+WSL1. I noticed that the sleep command doesn't work. After searching for the error, I found this issue https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4898

Then following one of the comments in there, I applied the following workaround:

```
wget "https://launchpad.net/~rafaeldtinoco/+archive/ubuntu/lp1871129/+build/19152555/+files/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu8+lp1871129~1_amd64.deb"
sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.31-0ubuntu8+lp1871129~1_amd64.deb
```

Now the sleep command works. But a lot of things stopped working, `apt upgrade` gives the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9) but 2.31-0ubuntu8+lp1871129~1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Trying to do what it suggests, which is `apt --fix-broken install`, I get the following error:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc6
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc6
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2713 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 63162 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9) over (2.31-0ubuntu8+lp1871129~1) ...
Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
sleep: cannot read realtime clock: Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libc6:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Question is, how can I reverse the change I did? Or how can I fix the above errors I get from apt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what you did here:

```
wget "https://launchpad.net/~rafaeldtinoco/+archive/ubuntu/lp1871129/+build/19152555/+files/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu8+lp1871129~1_amd64.deb"
sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.31-0ubuntu8+lp1871129~1_amd64.deb
```

the person creating that `.deb` could have fully compromised your computer. Following random instructions may be problematic.

If you were to install from that repo, you should have added to your software sources

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rafaeldtinoco/lp1871129/ubuntu focal main
```

that way, it would have been able to pull the dependencies (or refuse earlier).

Now, what happened was the following:

- You had glibc installed at version 2.31-0ubuntu9
- With those commands you installed version 2.31-0ubuntu8+lp1871129 (version 2.31-0ubuntu8 to which reafaeldtinoco added a patch). You *downgraded* to a previous glibc version
- libc package is used for pretty much every program in your system
- `apt --fix-broken install` is finding one solution: install back 2.31-0ubuntu9. However, the post-process step of installation fails because it uses `sleep`, which is now broken again.

Alternatively, you could downgrade everything to 2.31-0ubuntu8, but you might have a good number of packages to manually force to downgrade. Another solution would be to create a patched version of 2.31-0ubuntu9, but you would probably not be comfortable doing that.

Right now, you have 2.31-0ubuntu8 installed, but not configured.

It may be possible to force the downgrade to rafaeldtinoco libc6 version, and keep it at that by doing:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rafaeldtinoco/lp1871129 # Install rafaeldtinoco/lp1871129 repo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6=2.31-0ubuntu8+lp1871129~1 # Downgrade to exactly this version
sudo apt-mark hold libc6 # Do not upgrade libc6
```